# Javascript: Add new attribute to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<div id = "btnsdhd" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="31" value="SD" class="btn btn-default">SD</button>
    <button type="button" id="32" value="HD" class="btn btn-default">HD</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var btnsdhdDiv = $('#btnsdhd');

var getsdhd = function () {

  // Get all sdhd's from buttons with .active class
  var sdhd = $('button.active', btnsdhdDiv).map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  // If no sdhd's found, get sdhd's from any button.
  if (!sdhd || sdhd.length <= 0) {
    sdhd = $('button', btnsdhdDiv).map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();   
  }

  return sdhd;
};
```

The above code captures the values of the buttons and places it in the variable `getsdhd`

If none of the buttons are selected by default it captures both the values `(SD,HD)` I want to modify the `if` statement and add a third value `NC` to the variable when to no buttons are selected
I want it to look like `(SD,HD,NC)` when no buttons are slected.
I tried to use the `.push()` method but that didnt work.
Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Where did you use push?

Comment: @epascarello In the If statement, after the get method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push() can not be chained in your case since push returns the new length, not the updated array. You need to add it below the get().

```js
var btnsdhdDiv = $('#btnsdhd');

var getsdhd = function () {

  // Get all sdhd's from buttons with .active class
  var sdhd = $('button.active', btnsdhdDiv).map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  // If no sdhd's found, get sdhd's from any button.
  if (!sdhd || sdhd.length <= 0) {
    sdhd = $('button', btnsdhdDiv).map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get()
    sdhd.push("NC");   
  }

  return sdhd;
};

console.log(getsdhd());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "btnsdhd" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="31" value="SD" class="btn btn-default">SD</button>
    <button type="button" id="32" value="HD" class="btn btn-default">HD</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!! That exactly what I was looking for. I was trying the push method on `getsdhd` variable itself which now I realise is stupid. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking the getsdhs function. If you invoke your function it will work. I used `console.log` to test if it works.

**JS**

```
var btnsdhdDiv = $('#btnsdhd');

var getsdhd = function () {

  // Get all sdhd's from buttons with .active class
  var sdhd = $('button.active', btnsdhdDiv).map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  // If no sdhd's found, get sdhd's from any button.
  if (!sdhd || sdhd.length <= 0) {
    sdhd = $('button', btnsdhdDiv).map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    sdhd.push("NC");
  }

  console.log(sdhd);
  return sdhd;
}();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ABr/p23cb5dk/1/

Comment: Well @espascarello, I missed the "NC" part ;-) Added it to my answer.

Comment: And now getsdhd is not a method like the OP wanted. OP did not show all their code on how it was being used.